# How to rewrite url wordpress?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, site-url

i am doing WordPress posts filter. As a result of the application forms obtained this url:

```
http://local/rieltplus/category/catalog/?type=flat&price_min=1000&price_max=2000&area_min=5&area_max=50&room_num=5&etage=2&plan=old
```

How to rewrite the url like this:

local/rieltplus/category/catalog/**TYPE**&price_min=1000&price_max=2000&area_min=5&area_max=50&room_num=5&etage=2&plan=old

That is, **TYPE** = get the GET parameter type, and then the other parameters are unchanged. Please help me ... I do not know how to do it ...

Comment: `http://local/rieltplus/` is your homepage right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hook [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) into `init`

Assuming `http://local/rieltplus/` is your homepage, and `category/catalog/` is a category archives, this should work:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'category/catalog/([^/]+)?$',
        'index.php?category_name=catalog&type=$matches[1]&price_min=1000&price_max=2000&area_min=5&area_max=50&room_num=5&etage=2&plan=old',
        'top'
    );
});
```

If you want to make that available to any category then mention it in the comments.

By the way, `local/rieltplus/category/catalog/TYPE&price_min` is not a valid URL, unlike `local/rieltplus/category/catalog/TYPE?price_min` or `local/rieltplus/category/catalog/TYPE/?price_min`..

To get the `type` variable, use `get_query_var( 'type' )` but first add it to the main query:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function($vars) {
    $vars[] = "type";
    return $vars;
});
```

You should flush the permalink structure by saving your permalink structure in the `settings > permalinks` screen or using `flush_rewrite_rules()` ONLY ONCE.

**Edit** - As per your other question in [the comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227812/how-to-rewrite-url-wordpress/227818?noredirect=1#comment336714_227818)

```
add_action('wp', function() { // this will work as long as GET type is the first is the query string
    if( "catalog" === get_query_var( "category_name" ) && isset( $_GET["type"] ) ) {
        if( ! empty( $_GET["type"] ) ) {
            $type = strval( $_GET["type"] );
            $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
            $url = str_replace( array( "?type={$type}&", "?type={$type}" ), "{$type}?", $url );
            $url = str_replace( "?&", '?', $url );
            wp_redirect( $url );
            exit;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: "By the way, local/rieltplus/category/catalog/TYPE&price_min is not a valid URL" - yes, i did mistake

Comment: I am now check out your option. And then - be sure to agree.

Comment: See another question. I have a form that passes get parameters. How to redirect catalog/?type= **TYPE** to catalog/ **TYPE**

Comment: @IgorFedorov I edited the answer..